# enablevmaccess Provisioning Failed > Re-Install the VMAccessAgent

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machines, azure-powershell

I'm a bit of a newb with Azure VM extensions.  In a VM that I've inherited the management of, there is an extension that is not properly provisioned.

The VM is running Windows Server 2016 and I just installed Azure-Powershell, but most of their commands are not working, throwing various errors, including being blocked due to a .NET 4.7.2 or higher minimum framework reference.

*enablevmaccess*

- Type: Microsoft.Compute.VMAccessAgent
- Version: 2.4.7
- Status: Provisioning failed
- Status level: Error
- Status message: VMAccess Extension does not support Domain Controller.
- Handler status: Ready
- Handler status level: Info

From what I've read in various articles, this extension should be able to be used on this VM, even though it's running ADFS and connected to the domain.

What would be a safe and correct Powershell commandlet (or other method) to correctly reinstall this feature?

FYI - I know I can click the uninstall button on the extensions page, but after viewing so many videos about certain extensions needing to be installed via Powershell only and numerous commandlets not working for me, I'm nervous about using that option.

Answer (score 3):

That VM extension is used to reset the local password inside your VM. On a Domain Controller there is no "local" password to reset, so the extension doesn't support VMs running as Domain Controllers.

Since the extension can't do its job, it's showing up as a failed provisioning task for the extension. I would just remove the extension from the VM.